# How to get a struct for a first and last name defined and printed out in Rust?

Tags: rust

So if I were writing a struct of a person in Go let's say, the syntax would look like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type person struct {
  firstName string
  lastName string
}

func main() {
  dan := person{ firstName: "Daniel", lastName: "Dougherty" }
  fmt.Println(dan)
}
```

But in Rust:

```
use std::fmt;

struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String
}

fn main() {
    impl fmt::Display for Person {
        first_name: String::from("alex"),
        last_name: String::from("anderson")
    }
}
```

The above is the latest iteration because I keep having compile issues like the following:

```
Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground) error: expected one of `!`
or `::`, found `:`   --> src/main.rs:10:19    | 9  |     impl
fmt::Display for Person {    |                                  -
while parsing this item list starting here 10 |         first_name:
String::from("alex"),    |                   ^ expected one of `!` or
`::` 11 |         last_name: String::from("anderson") 12 |     }    | 
- the item list ends here

error[E0046]: not all trait items implemented, missing: `fmt`  -->
src/main.rs:9:5   | 9 |     impl fmt::Display for Person {   |    
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ missing `fmt` in implementation   |   =
help: implement the missing item: `fn fmt(&self, _: &mut
Formatter<'_>) -> Result<(), std::fmt::Error> { todo!() }`
```

I really just want to get going with something equivalent to what you see in the Go version.

Comment: That's not valid Rust code. A) `impl` doesn't belong inside a function. B) `impl` *requires* you to implement the functions that trait needs. You can't just bash in code.

Comment: @tadman You absolutely can have `impl` in a function.

Comment: @Deadbeef You can, but in this case it doesn't make sense, it doesn't belong.

Comment: Thanks guys, I started following the suggestions the errors were giving me, and as a newbie, not understanding enough about such syntax as `impl`. So yeah it feels like code bashing right now and I hate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use struct syntax, and derive a debug impl.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person {
        first_name: String::from("alex"),
        last_name: String::from("anderson")
    };

    println!("{person:?}");
}
```

Comment: I actually understand your answer a bit, in that using that `#[derive(Debug)]` trait, all types can automatically derive as opposed to having to be manually done, which I was doing by using `fmt::Display`.  Just now understood this by reading here: https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/hello/print/print_debug.html